# GeoLocation API error handling

Tags: javascript, html, error-handling, geolocation

So I have this code... problem is that when Firefox asks me for my location, and I reject it, it never runs the error function.  Why?

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(savePosition, noPosition);
} else { noPosition(null); }

function savePosition(position) {
    current.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    current.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
}

function noPosition(error) {
    alert("Aaa");
}
```

Comment: The code seems fine to me. Did you test it with Firefox only?

Comment: Yes only with Firefox... does Firefox not allow this or something then?

Comment: Keep in mind that geolocation is supported by IE9+ only, and that Chrome is the most common browser in the world. You may want to check it with Chrome too (hint: in Chrome it works as expected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug, as you can see here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=675533

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is the current behavior of Firefox.  The same happens when you try their example on this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Using_geolocation

Comment: Great... Is this a bug or by design?

Comment: I'm not sure, according to the docs the error callback should happen.  You may want to submit a bug here if one doesn't exist already.  In the meantime, it looks like you have to deal with this behavior though.